# Dynamic Vuetify Textbox or Select based on Array Values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on a modal form which will display a number of [v-select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/) or [v-text-field](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/)... however, the number and types of these elements are being pulled from a database which means the vuetify code to create the elements needs to be dynamic. To start, I have a json object which is returned from the database which describes each input element. If the input is a v-select, then the json property called *InputType* is set to 'Combobox'. If it's a v-text-field then the *InputType* is set to 'Textbox'. Here's a sample.

```
{
  tags: [
    {
      TagDefinitionId: '1',
      InputType: 'Combobox',
      Name: 'Tag1',
      TagValueOptions: [
        {
          Value: 'Option 1',
        },
        {
          Value: 'Option 2',
        },
        {
          Value: 'Option 3',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      TagDefinitionId: '2',
      InputType: 'Textbox',
      Name: 'Project Name',
      TagValueOptions: [],
    },
  ],
}
```

Then, I'm using vuex to map the state in my modal to value called *documentTags*.

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'MyModal',
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['documentTags']),
  },
};
</script>
```

Now, up inside my vuetify template for my modal I know how to create separate columns for the number of elements in my *documentTags* array. I can do something like this:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="show" max-width="600px">
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        v-for="n in this.documentTags.tags.length"
        :key="n"
        cols="18"
        sm="8"
        md="6"
      >
        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
          This v-card needs to be replaced with a v-select or v-text-field
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

However, I really don't know how to walk through my *documentTags* array and determine which element (ie. v-select or v-text-field) needs to place in the appropriate column using the Vue and/or Vuetify syntax. Can anyone provide guidance on how this might be done?

**Update**

So, I updated my code according to Leonardo's suggestion (which works), but now I'm running into an issue. I don't know how to assign the tag Name to the label for each input object. I thought I could try something like *'tag.Name'* but that doesn't work. Any thoughts?

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="show" max-width="600px">
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        v-for="tag in this.documentTags.tags"
        :key="tag.TagDefinitionId"
        cols="18"
        sm="8"
        md="6"
      >
        <v-select
          v-if="tag.InputType === 'Combobox'"
          :items="tag.TagValueOptions"
          item-text="Value"
          label="tag.Name"
          required
        >
        </v-select>
        <v-text-field
          v-else-if="tag.InputType === 'Textbox'"
           label="tag.Name"
           required
        >
        </v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

**Update2**

Does anyone know how to access the value from the v-select or v-text-field since these elements are being dynamically created? Normally, I would use something like *v-model="name"* and then declare the *name* property inside the *data* prop section... However, I'm not exactly sure how to do those in this instance. Ideally, I'd like to package the inputs up into a JSON object with the tag name and it's value. So, something like this as an example (assuming we have two tags in this scenario).

```
"userDocumentTags": [{
    "Name": "Project Name",
    "Value": "My Project Name"
   },{
    "Name": "Project Number",
    "Value": "0001"
  }
]
```

I thought I could bind the property by doing something like this:

```
<v-select
  v-if="tag.InputType === 'Combobox'"
  :v-model="tag.Name"
  :items="tag.TagValueOptions"
  item-text="Value"
  label="tag.Name"
  required
></v-select>
```

And inside my data props section I have something like this:

```
data: () => ({
  userDocumentTags: [],   
}),
```

But, I don't know how to push the name and value pairs into the *userDocumentTags* object. Can anyone provide any guidance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="show" max-width="600px">
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        v-for="tag in this.documentTags.tags"
        :key="tag.TagDefinitionId"
        cols="18"
        sm="8"
        md="6"
      >
        <v-select v-if="tag.InputType === 'Combobox'">
           // you can customize this v-select
        </v-select>
        <v-text-field v-else-if="tag.InputType === 'Textbox'">
           // you can customize this v-text-field
        </v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

**Update:**

Hey dude, about you new doubt, in vue.js when you need pass a variable as a attribute you should use `:attribute="var"`.

Check some examples:

```
label="tag.Name" // label is equal a string "tag.Name"
label="7" // label is equal a string "7"
:label="tag.Name" // label is equal a value of tag.Name
:label="7" // label is equal a number 7
```

In your case, switch `label="tag.Name"` by `:label="tag.Name"`.

**One thing else...** Inside your template, you don't need use the directive `this` to access your data values. In your `for` statement try use `v-for="tag in documentTags.tags"`

**Update2**

If you wanna apply the changes in "real-time" for all your application, you can use this way: 
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#form-handling

You'll create a mutation method to update your vuex data and use the `input` or `change` event to call this mutation method.

Otherwise if you only wanna apply that changes after the user press a save button (per example), so you can't use the documentTags as a computed data. You'll need copy the `documentTags` value to your local data `userDocumentTags`. I guess you can do it in your `mounted` hook something like this:

```js
mounted() {
   this.userDocumentTags = [...this.$store.getters['documentTags']];
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce this example in my machine so I'm not sure if it'll work. Maybe you should open a new question asking what's the best way to resolve this new problem specifically.

Comment: I have one last follow up question. How do I bind the value of these combobox or text fields to properties that I can use in my methods? Normally, I would do something like `v-model="option"` and then declare `option` inside my `data` property. But, since these components are dynamic (meaning I don't exactly know the number of elements or their before compile time)... I don't really know how to get access to the values. Can you provide some pointers?

Comment: @andyopayne I'm not sure that I'll can help you this time. Maybe you should create a new question about it.